# Add Windows 8.1 project to Solution with Windows Phone 8.1 project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015, windows-8.1-universal

I have Windows Phone 8.0 (Silverlight) app that is retargeted to 8.1. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community if it matters.

**Question**

Is it possible to add Windows 8.1 app and Shared Project to solution?

**Goal**

I want to have a situation like when I've created universal windows's app and I can choose what app is building now, share some classes etc.

**Update**

So I've done like Igor told me. Now I have Windows 8.1 project and PCL in same solution. PCL is added as reference to both projects. But one thing is still missing.

Now my window look like this.

[image]
[image]

And I want to have this.

[image]

**Solution**
I had to create PCL and do like Igor told me to do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, shared project would make no sense because your phone app is Silverlight not WinRT so you would not be able to share much code.

Just create a Portable Class Library (PCL) targeting Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight and add as much code there as possible.

Comment: Ok that will take care of shared code part. What about adding Windows 8.1 to solution like in universal app. That is also not avalible at my situation and I had to create separated project for Windows 8.1?

Comment: Do not really understand your question. Just add a PCL and a WIndows 8.1 project to your solution.

Comment: Just try Clean+Rebuild and VS restart

Comment: Done it but still same result. At this moment in solution properties I've changed from `single startup project` to `current selection`

Comment: So maybe close VS, delete all .csproj.user file, open VS again and set the startup project by right clicking on it and Set startup project

Comment: That didn't help either. Maybe this something that worsk only on Universal Projects?